# IntelliJ IDEA plugin development: how to modify the Psi tree?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I would like to know what the "proper" way to create new PsiElement instances and add them to the Psi tree is.

I looked at the tutorial provided by JetBrains (http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/custom_language_support/quick_fix.html). The method they use there seems suitable for the simple properties language they introduce but I don't think it's the way to go with a more complicated syntax, where I want to add a child PsiElement that cannot appear at the root level of a PsiFile.

What would be best for me is to be able to parse a text snippet as an element and have it added to the tree. I tried to do something like this:

```
myLangTopElement.getNode().addLeaf(MyLangTypes.CHILD_EXPRESSION, "fish = '42'", null);
```

It actually seems to work - the text is added to the document and a node is created but when I edit the text inside the quotes in the editor - some exceptions are thrown...

What am I doing wrong? What is the correct way to add new elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PSI is complicated :(. A usual way is to create a whole file from a carefully prepared text (PsiFileFactory#createFileFromText), extract from it the PSI element you need to add into the tree, and then call PsiElement#add/addBefore/addAfter passing the extracted element as an argument. If your PSI element is a wrapper over AST (i.e. AstDelegatePsiElement), its add* methods already do the magic necessary for the exceptions not to be thrown.

You can study GrCreateSubclassAction#startTemplate from the IDEA CE source for an example, and the implementation of createCodeReferenceElementFromText that it calls.

Comment: Ok, createFileFromText works. To be honest it kind of feels like a hack but if that's the recommended way then ok :) One related small question: what is the best way to add something like a whitespace to the Psi tree? Do I need to go through createFileFromText even for that, or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Yes, I think it does feel like a hack, too. But PSI requires just too many things to work correctly, and this is the easiest way to get it. As for normal PsiWhiteSpace, please try PsiParserFacade.SERVICE.getInstance(project).createWhiteSpaceFromText()

Comment: Sorry this has been long. But Can someone point me to any documents/examples? I googled there are not even many results...