# Creating a psiElement in intelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I need to add some code to the existing code using my plugin but I need to add it as psiElements rather than as a string in the code.

I need to know if can I instantiate the elements in my code to psiElements and add it to the psiTree.

It will be more like PsiStatements being added to the code having some psiElements in them.

Answer (score 1):

From IntelliJ plugin development forum [thread](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206143839-Adding-PsiElements-to-a-PsiFile)

```
PsiElementFactory factory = file.getManager().getElementFactory();
PsiComment comment = factory.createCommentFromText(msg, file);
file.addBefore(comment, file.getFirstChild());
```

---

See also

1. Modifying source code section from plugin development [FAQ.](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/faq.html)
2. [IntelliJ IDEA plugin development: how to modify the Psi tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35713431/intellij-idea-plugin-development-how-to-modify-the-psi-tree)