# Create Java PsiAssignmentExpression

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, automated-refactoring

I'm trying to write a Java plugin that does a custom refactoring that involves inserting new assignment statements, and I'm not sure how to create a `PsiAssignmentExpression`.

I have a `PsiElementFactory`, but while I see `PsiElementFactory#createIdentifier` and `PsiElementFactory#createVariableDeclarationStatement`, I don't see how to do an assignment.

I tried looking for the extract variable refactoring in the base source code to try and find an example but wasn't able to find it yet.

P.S. I looked at [IntelliJ IDEA plugin development: how to modify the Psi tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35713431/intellij-idea-plugin-development-how-to-modify-the-psi-tree?s=3|1.5273), which recommended creating PsiElements by creating a `PsiFile` and then extracting the element from it back in, but I am wondering if that's specific to creating a custom language that doesn't have the Java api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `PsiElementFactory#createExpressionFromText` and pass in the text of the assignment you want to create. For example `"s = \"Hello World\""`.